# What caused this character to stop seeing the future?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

During the last episode of *Loki*, we learn that

> the person who controls the TVA can see anything that happens in the future – until a certain point. That point is when Loki and Sylvie are talking to him.

Why couldn't he see the future after then? Did it have something to do with Loki and Sylvie being there? Why does he have that power anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He can no longer see the future because they pass the threshold into new time. Time beyond that point is not being monitored by the TVA and has not yet been written. We see time start to branch.

> **He Who Remains:** We just crossed... the threshold. Oh. So, I fibbed. I fibbed earlier when I said I know how everything's going to go. I... I know... I knew... everything up to a certain point, and that point was about... seven, eight, nine, ten seconds ago. But now I have no idea. No idea how the rest of this is going to go. I'm being candid.
>
> <sub>*Loki*, Season 1 Episode 6, “For All Time, Always”</sub>

The reason he knows everything that will happen is because he has been dictating what is to happen. When talking though they cross past that point.

> **Loki:** How does it all end?
>
> **Mobius:** That's a work in progress.
>
> **Loki:** Oh, those lazy Time-Keepers. What are they waiting for?
>
> **Mobius:** Au contraire. No. Because while we protect what came before, they're toiling away in their chamber, untangling the epilogue from its infinite branches.
>
> <sub>*Loki*, Season 1 Episode 2, “The Variant”</sub>

Comment: So- "Kang" writes the future, and he didn't know he would pass the threshold? Why didn't he prevent that? And why did it happen exactly then?

Comment: @MBEllis he knew he would pass the threshold. He “fibbed”, remember. He was preventing it, that’s what he was doing but he didn’t want/couldn’t carry on anymore which is why he was recruiting the two Loki’s to do it.

Comment: @MBEllis: "he didn't know he would pass the threshold? Why didn't he prevent that?" My vague impression was that the threshold is a point in time; it's as far as he can see/determine. (A bit like the Ancient One not being able to see past her own death.) He couldn't prevent it from being passed without stopping time itself, which I'm assuming is impossible even with whatever his knowledge and skills are.

Comment: Ah so he was writing out how things would go, as they happened, but when Loki and Sylvie showed up he was like "this is a perfect opportunity to stop doing this" and thus crossed that threshold during their conversation?

Comment: @ZipZapJ Well he knew the point at where the threshold was i.e. the time that the TVA was monitoring up to for what he'd written. In simplified terms I believe what you're saying is correct.